# Why do turtles ride on alligators?

Tags: ethology

I often see pictures of turtles riding alligators, I even saw that in a zoo once, but why do they do that?

Is it some sort of camouflage technique for the turtles? And why doesn't the alligator get it off?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turtles will crawl onto anything to get out of the water and bask, fallen logs are common and they likely cannot tell the difference between a still alligator and a log.  It might also be possible that the turtles do know what the gator is and are hoping to tag along and pick up scraps after it strikes.

I image that for the gators thrashing around to dislodge the turtle has to high a risk of scaring off prey so they just put up with it. 
[image]